# How to pass array into meta_query value with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin with WordPress. I am using relationship custom field.

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'slos_trainings',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'lokacija', // name of custom field
                'value' =>  79,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
```

I would like to pass array into meta_query value. Currently my code is working and it is returning all custom post types slos_trainings that have location custom meta field set to 79. But this field is a relationship, so it can have multiple ID-s. For example I want to find all posts with type slos_trainings that have lokacija set to 79 OR 200 OR 124, etc,..

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `'value' =>  array(79, 200, 124)`. And for search use `in_array(79, $array['meta_query']['value'])`

Comment: Hi @Bora. Nope, I've tried:
    'value' =>  array(79)

and


    'value' =>  array('79'),

None of this works, I get wrong results or no results at all.

Comment: Could you paste your action so finding codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slos_trainings',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'lokacija',
            'value' => array ( 79, 200, 124),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```